# Why does the cast appear on stage at the end of every episode?

Tags: saturday-night-live

At the conclusion of every episode of Saturday Night Live, the entire cast, including any special guests and the musical guest, appears on stage while the host thanks the cast and crew and says goodnight (with slight variations therein). Those on the stage hug, laugh, and seem to have light chit chat while the credits role.

*Why is this done?*

Comment: My first thought is that it is a theater tradition that SNL adopted, but I don't know for sure...

Comment: Not sure what else it would be... it's a live show that just happens to be broadcast on TV. It's the same thing as the closing bows that occur at the end of any stage performance.

Comment: Because they have to figure out who's giving who a ride to the after party. Just kidding, it's tradition.

Answer (score 5):

Saturday Night Live is a live theatrical performance, filmed in front of a live audience.  Many similar shows close/have closed this way, including In Living Color.